# To display amount in thousand seperator and add two zero's after decimal point in <md-input-container> tag

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<td md-cell class="min-width-120px-imp text-right padding-right-10">
  <md-input-container flex class="margin-0" ng-show="!vm.grn.itemdetails[$index].isfree">
      <label translate class="padding-left-0">COMMON.UNITPRICE</label>
      <input id="grnUnitPrice{{$index}}" name="grnUnitPrice{{$index}}" class="text-right" type="number" enterastab ng-required="!vm.grn.itemdetails[$index].isfree" ng-model="vm.grn.itemdetails[$index].unitprice" ng-pattern="vm.amountPattern" ng-change="vm.updateTaxAmount($index, true);"
          flex ng-readonly="vm.grn.itemdetails[$index].isfree" update-decimals-on-blur="vm.iUtil.amountDecimal" />
  </md-input-container>
  <md-input-container flex class="margin-0" ng-show="vm.grn.itemdetails[$index].isfree">
      <label translate class="padding-left-0">COMMON.UNITPRICE</label>
      <input id="grnUnitPriceFree{{$index}}" name="grnUnitPriceFree{{$index}}" class="text-right" type="number" enterastab ng-required="vm.grn.itemdetails[$index].isfree" value="0.000" override-dai="true" ng-disabled="true" />
  </md-input-container>
  <div ng-messages="grnForm['grnUnitPrice' + $index].$error" md-auto-hide="false">
      <div ng-message-exp="['pattern']" translate>ERRORS.INVALIDVALUE</div>
  </div>
</td>
```

Example:
If I enter `15987` in input field, it should display as `15,987.00`

Comment: You might want to add `angular` to your tag list

Comment: and `angular-material` too

Comment: sorry. Can't understand what you are saying

Comment: can u check this example it will help u https://plnkr.co/edit/PiMWdveQfLKwEoaUqGxP?p=preview

Comment: In the above code, you will find second md-input-container tag with ng-disabled ="true" .  In this place, i want thousand seperator and two zero's after decimal point

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Kondaldurgam/nzK4n/114/ Check this